# What is the difference between the following two constructors of TreeSet?

Tags: java, collections

For the `TreeSet<E>` the following two constructors are defined:

1. `TreeSet<E>(Collections<? extends E> c)`
2. `TreeSet<E>(SortedSet<E> ss)`

What is the need for the second option? Wouldn't the first contructor be compatible with the entire collections framework range of objects?
I.e., if there is a scenario where we need to convert a SortedSet to TreeSet obj, can't we use the first contructor method?

Please clarify in this regard.

Comment: Did you even read the [API doc of `TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) for those constructors? It explains the difference.

Comment: rtfm: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the specified comparator.
TreeSet(SortedSet<E> s)
Constructs a new tree set containing the same elements and using the same ordering as the specified sorted set.

Comment: Who the heck is blindly downvoting all of the answers?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Probably the same people who blindly downvote a legitimate question. I'm sure OP read the documentation, but missed the part where it talks about the same ordering, perhaps because he never used a custom comparator for his tree set.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight imho, the question is not legitim in that way. The java-docs here are really clear. the constructors are in a separate table with parameter and description. [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#constructor_summary) The question doesn't show ANY research-effort.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to being a `Collection<E>`, `SortedSet<E>` provides access to its custom comparator:

```
Comparator<? super E> comparator()
```

This overload of the constructor lets the newly created `TreeSet<E>` use the same custom sorter as that of the sorted set being copied.

Here is the code that demonstrates the difference:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Set<String> a = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    SortedSet<String> b = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    populate(a);
    show(a, "Original a");
    populate(b);
    show(b, "Original b");
    Set<String> copyA = new TreeSet<String>(a);
    show(copyA, "Copy of a");
    Set<String> copyB = new TreeSet<String>(b);
    show(copyB, "Copy of b");
}
static void populate(Set<String> s) {
    s.add("A");
    s.add("aa");
    s.add("B");
    s.add("bb");
}
static void show(Set<String> s, String name) {
    System.out.println("============ "+name+" ==========");
    for (String t : s) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
============ Original a ==========
A
aa
B
bb
============ Original b ==========
A
aa
B
bb
============ Copy of a ==========
A
B
aa
bb
============ Copy of b ==========
A
aa
B
bb
```

Note how the order of copied `a` is different from the original order, while the order of copied `b` remains consistent with the original.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/7MNfCA)

Answer (score 3):

The `TreeSet(SortedSet ss)` constructor uses the same ordering as the `ss` parameter, while the `TreeSet(Collections c)` forcibly uses the "natural ordering" of its elements.

The [Javadoc for `java.util.TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) explains that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first case, the *natural ordering* of the elements of the collection is maintained, while in the second case, the ordering of the `SortedSet` is maintained. The distinguishing factor is the ordering of the elements in the `TreeSet`.

You can also set a custom ordering using the other constructor of the `TreeSet`.

Just check out the documentations for further reference.